# Xcode unity plugin error: "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7"

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

today this is my headache, I hope someone can help me:

Context: A simple iOS app that need one method implemented by a unity-xcode plugin. (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

More details Xcode: 5.1.1 Unity: 4.5.1f3

I tried a simple plugin unity-xcode, when I run the project (xcode), the error appear:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"__savePicture", referenced from:
RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Important to mention when I run the project without plugin-stuff, all is fine, the app runs in my ipad without problems.

I just generate a ".h" and ".m" and add that files to classes folder in the generated xcode project, It´s a simple call method in my c# code:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern void _savePicture(string nom);
```

can you help me? I tried different settings since Unity, with hope that make it work , but it doesn't happen.

related topic:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-help.198242/